# Running windows phone application on phone event (like call ended / reejected)

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to get notification/event/run application when call is rejected?
If so is it possible to get the number that was rejected? (I know it's not possible to access call log).

Bonus question. Where can i find documentation on phone events/notifications (Microsoft UI team spent to much designing guidelines for developers, and to little designing their own site, so you can actually find something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as API is concerned this is not possible and I don't know about any other way.

Comment: Thanks. "It's not possible", or "disabled for security reasons" seems to be recurring theme for WP7 so far.

Comment: Can you blame them in this circumstance? I don't think I want events available for Call Begin/End to apps. Sounds like an easy way to make an app which launches at call begin, records audio data and uploads, then closes at call end. Generally Microsoft's stance is to only run apps when the user explicitly launches them, it seems.

I tend to wonder though if you couldn't use a clever implementation of the OnAppActivated/Deactivated with some input from the user on what exactly happened in-call. Not intuitive, but those two events will tell  you when the user leaves/returns.

Comment: Yea I can blame them :) Making calls/recording is one thing. Adding a hook to notify app call is starting/ending is a whole another. Especially since user have to agree on it. Anyway lack of this makes making apps that actually improve/change normal workflow is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this is not possible with wp7 Mango release