# Detecting when phone call task ended

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I need to detect when phone call made using phone call task (involved from my appliaction) ended. It should works like this:

1. User tries to call to someone - the phone call task launches.
2. User selects 'call' and then phone starts to call.
3. When call ends phone automatically returns to app. My app should be aware of the fact that phone call ended and show history of recent calls (basically another view).

I tried using OnNavigatedFrom event but it is not firing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running windows phone application on phone event (like call ended / reejected)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172087/running-windows-phone-application-on-phone-event-like-call-ended-reejected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. The Windows Phone SDK does not fire events when calls end. The Windows Phone 7 OS considers that privileged information that your applications do not need to access.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does the same apply to WP8?